# google maps api v2 map.removeOverlay() marker array issue

Tags: api

To start off with, I would like to say that I have been looking on the internet for a really long time and have been unable to find the answer, hence my question here.

My latest school project is to create an admin page for adding articles to a database, the articles are connected to a point on a google map. The requirement for adding the point on the map is that the user is able to click the map once and the marker is produced, if the map is clicked a second time the first marker is moved to the second location. (this is what I am struggling with.)

The problem is, as the code is now, I get the error that markersArray is undefined. If I place the var markersArray = new Array; underneath the eventListener then I get an error that there is something wrong the main.js (googles file) and markersArray[0] is undefined in the second if.

By the way, I have to use google maps API v2, even though it is old.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var map;
var markers = new Array;  

function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    this.map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    this.map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    this.map.setCenter(new GLatLng(57.668911, 15.203247), 7);       

    GDownloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      var Articles = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("article");
      for (var i = 0; i < Articles.length; i++) {
        var id = Articles[i].getAttribute("id");
        var title = Articles[i].getAttribute("title");
        var text = Articles[i].getAttribute("text");
        var searchWord = Articles[i].getAttribute("searchWord");
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(Articles[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(Articles[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var article = createMarker(point, id, title, text);
        this.map.addOverlay(article);           
      }
    });
  }

var myEventListener = GEvent.bind(this.map,"click", this, function(overlay, latlng) {

  if (this.counter == 0) {
    if (latlng) {
        var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
        latlng1 = latlng;
        this.map.addOverlay(marker);
        this.counter++;
        markers.push(marker); //This is where I get the error that markersArray is undefined.

  } 
} 
else if (this.counter == 1) {
  if (latlng){
    alert (markers[0]);
    this.map.removeOverlay(markers[0]);
    var markers = [];
    this.map.addOverlay(marker);
    this.counter++;
  }
} 

}); 
}

function createMarker(point, id, title, text) {
  var article = new GMarker(point);
  var html = "<b>" + title + "</b> <br/>"
  GEvent.addListener(article, 'click', function() {
    window.location = "article.php?id=" + id;

  });
  return article;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I'm not exactly sure why it worked but this is what it looks like now:

```
var markersArray = [];

function load() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    this.map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    this.map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    this.map.setCenter(new GLatLng(57.668911, 15.203247), 7);       

GDownloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
var xml = GXml.parse(data);
var Articles = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("article");
    for (var i = 0; i < Articles.length; i++) {
        var id = Articles[i].getAttribute("id");
        var title = Articles[i].getAttribute("title");
        var text = Articles[i].getAttribute("text");
        var searchWord = Articles[i].getAttribute("searchWord");
        var type = Articles[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(Articles[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(Articles[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var article = createMarker(point, id, title, text);
        this.map.addOverlay(article);           
      }
    });
  }

var myEventListener = GEvent.bind(this.map,"click", this, function(overlay, latlng) {
var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
if (this.counter == 0) {
    if (latlng) {
        latlng1 = latlng;
        this.map.addOverlay(marker);    
        markersArray.push(marker);      
        this.counter++; 

  } 
 } 
else if (this.counter == 1) {
    if (latlng){
        this.map.removeOverlay(markersArray[0]);
        this.map.addOverlay(marker);
        this.counter++;
  }
} 

}); 
}

function createMarker(point, id, title, text) {
var article = new GMarker(point);
var html = "<b>" + title + "</b> <br/>"
GEvent.addListener(article, 'click', function() {
    window.location = "article.php?id=" + id;
});
return article;
}
```